# How to prevent text from going below an image when the height of text exceed the height of the image?

Tags: html, css

I use the following to display an image on the left side and any related info on the right side of the image. In some cases where description, address and other info exceed the height of the image, the text goes below the image. My question is how should I keep the text for not going under the image, but to continue like a column?

```
.eventphoto 
{
   padding:1px;
   width:200px; 
   float:left;
   margin-right:15px;
   border-radius:2px;
}
.desc 
{
   font-size:0.8em;
   line-height:13pt; 
}


<div class="desc">

<img class="eventphoto" src="">

<div style="float:left;">
<p>DESCRIPTION</p>
.
.
.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we take a look at the rendered page somewhere?

Comment: @LeeTaylor yes, sorry corrected it

Comment: Have your tried overflow:hidden on the desc class?

Comment: @carl-lopez I have added a screenshot of my current effort. It is supposed to be on the right side of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly-standard construct: the [media object](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/)

In your case, if we add Nicole's styles like so:

```
<style>
  .eventphoto 
  {
    padding:1px;
    width:200px; 
    margin-right:15px;
    border-radius:2px;
  }
  .desc 
  {
    font-size:0.8em;
    line-height:13pt; 
  }

  .media {margin:10px;}
  .media, .bd {overflow:hidden; _overflow:visible; zoom:1;}
  .media .img {float:left; margin-right: 10px;}
  .media .img img{display:block;}
  .media .imgExt{float:right; margin-left: 10px;}
</style>
```

(leaving the formatting to your original classes), and add a wrapper around the image with the appropriate styles:

```
<div class="desc media">

  <div class="img">
    <img class="eventphoto" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
  </div>

  <div class="bd">
    <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
    <p> ... </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

All works well. See this CodePen for an example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/JDsKa

Answer (score 0):

Try float:left on the image and float:right on the text like:

```
.eventphoto 
{
    padding:1px;
    width:200px; 
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
    border-radius:2px;
}
.desc 
{
    font-size:0.8em;
    line-height:13pt; 
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `overflow: hidden;` is your best bet. Here's a demo of it in use:

http://jsbin.com/owesiw/1/edit